# how do you print out errors from curl command

Tags: python, shlex

I am trying to use shlex library to run a curl command. I need to print out the errors. I have done the following but I dont see any errors.

```
import shlex
url='test.com'
args = shlex.split(url)

process = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
print(stderr)
```

It is not pringing any errors. Any ideas?

Comment: Firstly, the url variable is being assigned with an invalid string. The opening quote is a single quote while the closing quote is double.

Comment: Why are you running a `curl` command instead of just using python's `request` module? This question shows how much harder you're making it on yourself.

Comment: if it doesn't display errors then maybe there is no errors - maybe it works correctly. Did you test the same command directly in shell?